# JavaScript if else statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some problem with my if else statment for my radiobutton form. You can view it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDGGS/20/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input").click(function() {
        $check = true;
    });

    $("#next1").click(function() {
        if ($check) {
            $("boks1").hide();
            $("boks2").show();
        } else {
            alert('Pick one');
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="boks1">
<h1>What would you like to answer? </h1>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="0">Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1">Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2">Answer 3<br>
<div id="next1" style="border:1px solid black;">Next question<div>
</div>
<div id="boks2">
<h1>What would you like NOT to answer? </h1>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="0">Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="1">Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="2">Answer 3<br>
<div id="next2">Next question 3<div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boks2 {display:none;}
#next1 {display:block;}
```

Why is there not alert raised when I click on next and no radiobuttons have been selected? And why I am not shown the next question when I have selected one and clicked on the next div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are missing the `#` from your `id` selectors:

```
$("#boks1").hide();
$("#boks2").show();
```

However, you should declare the `$check` variable in the parent scope of the two functions (so  inside the `ready` event handler):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $check = false;
});
```

Otherwise, if you click on the "next" button before selecting a radio button, `$check` will not be defined. And when it does become defined, it's in the global scope, which is not a good thing.

Comment: Not actually true; works fine as long as `$check` is defined.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, I just said `$check` won't be defined if you click on the button before clicking an `input` element, since `$check` is currently defined in the `click` event handler.

Comment: (I was partially wrong anyway, I was referring only to the popup, not the hide/show, so never mind.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UDGGS/32/ Why is then the #boks2 not showed when I click next?

Comment: @Railsbeginner - Well spotted, I just noticed it too! Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2):

Defining the variable and then setting it to true when the input is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var = $check;

        $("input").click(function() {
            $check = true;
        });

        $("#next1").click(function() {
            if ($check) {
                $("#boks1").hide();
                $("#boks2").show();
            } else {
                alert('Pick one');
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable in the outer scope. Also the ids selectors inside ``` if`` block are missing ```#`. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $check; 
    $("input").click(function() {
        $check = true;
    });

    $("#next1").click(function() {
        if ($check) {
            $("#boks1").hide();
            $("#boks2").show();
        } else {
            alert('Pick one');
        }
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UDGGS/26/)**

Instead of using variable to find if the radio button is checked or not you can do this.

Note: I am using `$("input:checked").length > 0` to find out if any radio button is checked using `:checked` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#next1").click(function() {
        if ($("input:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#boks1").hide();
            $("#boks2").show();
        } else {
            alert('Pick one');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UDGGS/27/)**

Comment: There's no need to make it global and pollute the global namespace; it can be defined in the on-ready function.

Comment: Yes that can be done, edited my answer. I have provided alternative easy way also.

Comment: isn't the variable pinned to the global scope if it's declared in another scope without a `var` statement? I think that the problem lies within the bad jQuery selectors.

Comment: Yes, the selectors are missing `#`, modified answer.

Comment: @gion_13 - yes, the `$check` variable is in the global scope - but this is a **bad idea** and Shankar is correct to rectify it.

Comment: Yes, the variables will be in global scope if you don't use `var`. But since you are defining it inside `click` handler. Before you click on radio button, if you click on next div the variable is not defined so it doesn't work.